# Is there any convenient way to set display settings when using i3?

Tags: display-settings, high-dpi

I've found many commands that infuence how big things are on the screen

```
xrandr --dpi
xrandr --scale
Xft.dpi in ~./Xresources
export QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR=1
```

So far I haven't been successful in making i3 and applications have coherent sizes on both screens.

Can you guide me in how to combine these and other settings? Is there perhaps a higher level utility I could use?